# Switch branches with tortoisegit

Tags: git, branch, switch-statement, tortoisegit

I cloned a git respository on my hard disc. This git repository contains not only the master but also a branch called newBranch. How can I checkout the new branch with tortoisegit?

I tried it with the switch/checkout command but nothing changed in my local files. What works is when I clone the two branches in different folders like but I want to get it working with tortoisegit.

git clone localhost:testProject

differs from

git clone localhost:testProject newBranch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a checkbox option `Force` when switching branches in TortoiseGit.
Other than that, I must admit I'm stumped to.

Comment: that doesn't change anything ... the files are still the same

Comment: they are not when I switch branches. What versionsare you using? *TortoiseGit 1.5.8.0 - Git 1.7.3.1*

Comment: Sorry, my fault, an exception was shown by tortoise git that a lock existed already but also tortoise showed "success",I rebooted my computer, removed the sources and tried the same thing now it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

- Right click base folder and choose "Git Clone...".
- In the popup, give the Git repository path, choose appropriate local folder
- select the Branch option and type-in your branch name. Click Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings from the context menu.
General->Context Menu->Select 'Switch/Checkout'.

Afterwards it will be visible in the context menu.